# I've been programming a hangman game but i have a trouble with it, wish you can help me

Tags: java

I'm programming a hangman game, but i have problems with something, this is the entire script:

```
package prueba.ahorcado;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PruebaAhorcado {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        int vidas = 3;
        int aciertos = 0;
        int tamaño;
        String incognita = "";
        String signo = " _";
        int veces=0;
        int victoria=0;


        String[] palabras = new String[]{"CASO","TIEMPO","VIDA","PAIS","CAMPO","CAMBIO","MANOS","FALTA","SEGURIDAD","MERCADO"};   
        String palabra = (palabras[new Random().nextInt(palabras.length)]);
        char[] a = palabra.toCharArray();
        char[] b = incognita.toCharArray();
        tamaño = palabra.length();

        while (veces!=tamaño)
        {
        incognita=incognita+signo;
        veces++;
        }

        while(aciertos!=tamaño){

        System.out.println("Vidas: " + vidas);
        System.out.println(palabra);
        System.out.println(incognita);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String opcion = scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        if (palabra.contains(opcion))
        {
            int Indice = palabra.indexOf(opcion);
            System.out.println(Indice);
            //The problem is here

            aciertos++;


        }
        else
        {
            vidas = vidas-1;
        }
        if (vidas==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Has perdido");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        }

        if (aciertos==tamaño)
        {
            System.out.println("Has ganado");

        }

    }
```

And the problem is in the part that have to change the _ to the answered letter and then print it. For example: If the word is "CASO" it will print

```
Vidas: 3
(  _ _ _ _
```

And if i type "C" it have to print:

```
C _ _ _
```

Comment: OK, so that's what you need it to do; what does it do instead?

Comment: So... I wrote code (in Spanish), please fix it? Please write a proper description of your problem, instead of *i have problems with something*

Comment: Side note: declare and initialize the `Scanner` and the `Random` outside the loops. You only need one `Scanner`, and declaring a new `Random` restarts its internal pseudorandom number generator, which is both unnecessary and undesirable.

Comment: If i program to myself i don't need to do it in english xD

Comment: @Willdune so keep programming yourself, what's the deal here then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... my first answer to any question here, please be forgiveable ;)

I believe the best way is to use `replace` method in `StringBuilder` object. Like that:

```
 if (palabra.contains(opcion))
    {
        int Indice = palabra.indexOf(opcion);
        incognita = new StringBuilder( incognita ).replace( 1+2*Indice, 2+2*Indice, opcion ).toString();
        System.out.println(Indice);
        aciertos++; 
    }
```

The `1+2*Indice` index carries the proper position in your `incognita` String.

The line I wrote is not perfect though. It doesn't work properly when you type the same letter for the second time. Well, I think that's something you should think out by yourself.

Please, work on the pureness of your code too. Object names, like `Indice` shouldn't be started with a capital letter. Don't use 'ñ's in the names of variables. Also try to use indentations and new lines in a more logical way. That would work better both for you and us here.

And really, really start coding in English. Good luck.

Comment: No one has to code in English. That's very parochial. The JLS explicitly declares that Java supports using native-language identifiers; there's nothing wrong with that. There is, however, something wrong with violating the Java naming conventions, as does `Indice`.

Comment: Of course, no one HAS TO code in English. It's not parochial, but just convenient. If you expect to find help on English-based site, you'll probably get it sooner by writing your code in an approachable way to as many users as possible. Also, English variable names generally make code more consistent with all the syntax. Well, that wasn't an order of mine, more like a good suggestion. I used to code in my native language, now I feel kinda weird about it ;)

Comment: It is possible something like this?: 


incognita = new StringBuilder( incognita ).replace( 1+2*Indice, opcion ).toString(); 

I mean, instead of adding it, replacing it. Becouse it prints (following the example i make with CASO):

If i type O it return something like this:

 _ _ _ O_

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You should use the `replace` method, not `insert`. I Corrected that in the answer.

Comment: Now yes! Thanks a lot m8